# scrollTop only working sometimes

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am using 'scrollTop' to automatically scroll to the top of a div '#gallery-view'.

The offset is outputting the correct measurement, but on load, the 'scrollTop' is only scrolling to the point correctly 1 in 5 times. If I resize, it triggers it correctly and it works fine. It appears to be something to do with the 'on load'.

Strangely, the removal of the 'invisible' class below the 'scrollTop' works, so the code is run.

I can't see anything wrong with the following code, so thought I would ask you all.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {

    var viewportHeight;

    function winResize() {

        viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height();   

        if ( jQuery('#gallery-view').length ) {

            // GALLERY IMAGE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            var detailsHeight = jQuery('.details').outerHeight(true);
            var calc = (viewportHeight - detailsHeight) - (40 * 2);

            if ( calc >= 1000 ) {
                jQuery('.gallery-image-container img').css('max-height', '1000');
            } else if ( calc <= 400 ) {
                jQuery('.gallery-image-container img').css('max-height', '300');
            } else {
                jQuery('.gallery-image-container img').css('max-height', calc);
            }

            jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('#gallery-view').offset().top);
            jQuery('body').removeClass('invisible');

        }

    }
    jQuery(window).resize(winResize); 
    winResize();

});
```

Comment: `window.onLoad != document.ready` wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function () { //code });` see if it makes any change

Comment: @Stavm Running the code in document.ready isn't making any difference.